# Google Sheets Script Approval

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have created a spreadsheet that uses a simple script to make buttons function. The sheet has become very popular and I am getting tons of downloads daily - but some people are afraid to "allow" my script because how awful Google makes it sound (I totally understand it, but it keeps saying it is not approved and could be malicious and so on).

1. How do I go about getting the script approved? I thought I did the right steps but never heard anything.
2. My spreadsheet is always evolving and new versions might have changes to the script, so will I have to get new approval every time I update the sheet?

Comment: take a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable but if I understand your issue correctly, then the best you can do is to pack your script as an addon and publish it that's the "google solution" for the masses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tl; Dr

1. Create a Google Cloud Standard Project and take note of the project id
2. Complete the OAuth Consent Screen. At this end of this, it will be sent to verification
3. Add the project id to the Google Apps Script project

For the detailed instructions go to the official help articles (listed below)

References

- [Cloud Platform Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects)
- [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)
- [OAuth Client Verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification)